# Queries on large table extremely slow, how can I optimize?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

I have a database table with about 3.25 million rows. I'm experiencing extremely slow query times for simple queries, I don't think I'm trying to do anything crazy. I have basically zero knowledge of database optimization, so hopefully this is a simple fix.

The table holds contract data records, with an amount, a date, and some IDs related to other tables (`VendorId`, `AgencyId`, `StateId`), this is the database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VendorContracts]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,   
    [ContractDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ContractAmount] [decimal](19, 4) NULL, 
    [VendorId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AgencyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StateId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,

    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_VendorContracts] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have these 3 indexes on the database. I didn't create these, looks like Entity Framework Core did automatically with a migration, so they could be wrong or something.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_VendorContracts_AgencyId] 
ON [dbo].[VendorContracts] ([AgencyId] ASC)
         WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
               ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_VendorContracts_StateId] 
ON [dbo].[VendorContracts] ([StateId] ASC)
         WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
               ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_VendorContracts_VendorId] 
ON [dbo].[VendorContracts] ([VendorId] ASC)
         WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
               ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a page on my site where I'd like users to be able to select a vendor, and see the total amount of contract amounts, split by state.

I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(ContractAmount), StateId
FROM [dbo].[VendorContracts]
WHERE VendorId = '...'
GROUP BY StateId
```

But it takes forever, like 15 - 20 minutes.

I tried other simpler queries, I figured maybe the SUM was slowing everything down, but those are incredibly slow too. I tried querying by vendor and state:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[VendorContracts]
WHERE VendorId = '...' AND StateId = '...'
```

And even though it only returns a couple thousands rows, it still takes way too long.

[image]

[image]

The strange this is that I have another database on a separate server with a similar table, that has about 6 million records, and it doesn't have issues like this at all. I can run the SUM query and other queries in less than a second or two. And that database table has the same indexes, so not sure why that one is so efficient, and this one isn't.

I've been inserting hundreds of thousands of records each day the past week, and I reorganized the indexes, but that didn't fix the issue, is there something else I need to do to optimize this? My database is on Azure, do I maybe need to change increase some settings or something?

Comment: Try to create composite clustered index on the columns that are being used in the where clause.

Comment: Those indexes likely aren't going to help any of those queries. For the first, for example, you could use the `INDEX` on `VendorId` (`IX_VendorContracts_VendorId`) to find the specific rows, but that `INDEX` *only* contains the value of `VendorId` and you want the values of `Amount` and `StateId` too. This means that if the data engine did use that index it would have to then do a key lookup on the `CLUSTERED INDEX` or heap index. YOu likely need to `INCLUDE` the columns you need in your indexes too.

Comment: @NayanishDamania  the OP's Primary key is clustered (though they may well not be the best candidate for a clustered index, considering that it's a `uniqueindentifier` and isn't defaulted to be `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`). That suggestion, however, won't help the data engine in other respects, and would mean the OP would need to `DROP` and recreate their primary key.

Comment: @Larnu - so I should create a clustered index with columns `VendorId`, `StateId`, and `ContractAmount` for that `SUM()` query?

Comment: That's not what I said at all, @Steven . That's what Nayanish Damania suggests, and I suggested *against* that.

Comment: @Larnu - oh, I thought that's what you meant when you said "that INDEX only contains the value of VendorId and you want the values of Amount and StateId too". What would you suggest?

Comment: *"You likely need to `INCLUDE` the columns you need in your indexes."* `INCLUDE` is a keyword (hence why it's in code markdown). See the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#i-create-an-index-with-included-non-key-columns) in the documentation.

Comment: @Larnu - gotcha, just looked up `INCLUDE` in indexes, I'll give that a shot. Sorry, I'm an extreme novice with indexes.

Comment: @Larnu - that did it, I was able to `SUM` the contract amounts grouped by regions on a vendor with 500,000 records in under a second :) thank you so much, I'd love to give you kudos if you put your comment as an answer.

Comment: For the first query you are likely to want an index `VendorContracts (VendorId, StateId) INCLUDE (ContractAmount)` For the second you are always going to struggle because of `SELECT *`, the only way to cover that completely is to `INCLUDE` every column, which is ridiculous.

Comment: @Charlieface: Your comment makes it sound like only covering indexes are good indexes. This is not true of course. The first query requires an index on (VendorId, StateId) to be fast, which can be even more useful if ContractAmount gets included. The second query requires an index on (VendorId, StateId), too. Thus the index you are suggesting in your answer is appropriate for both queries. It doesn't have to include all columns of the table to be useful for the second query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner True, but then you need a `Key Lookup` in the execution plan which slows things down. Not a major problem if it's only a small number of rows, whereas a lot of rows is going to be slow. Which is why I stressed `SELECT *` as being problematic because it has so many columns, a small number of columns could be covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your indexes do not *cover* your query. In other words: the server cannot service your query by using just one index, so either it will have to do a key lookup for every row, or more likely it will choose to just scan the whole table.

Generally, single-column indexes are not very useful for precisely this reason. You can change one of your existing indexes.

- You want the equality `=` predicates from your `WHERE` to be the first columns in the index key.
- Then you add in join columns and grouping columns. It is normally only worth it to add one of these at this stage, unless a join is on a unique value.
- Finally, add in all other columns. These do not have to be part of the key, they can be `INCLUDE` columns.

For example:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_VendorContracts_VendorId] ON [dbo].[VendorContracts]
  (VendorId, StateId)
INCLUDE
  (ContractAmount)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON);
```